# How to transform to create a new List such that each object in list has only one element in the nested list each using Java?

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-11

I have two classes that look like:

```
public class A {
    String a;
    String b;
    String v;
    List<Pmt> pmtList;
}

public class Pmt {
    String id;
    String b;
    List<Transaction> trList;
}
```

How to transform to create a new payment list that can replace current payment list (`pmtList`) such that each payment object has only one `Transaction` each using Java?

Can someone please suggest how we can implement this logic? Each payment in a payment list can have multiple attributes which should not be modified. For example: if we have 5 payments in existing payment list and each payment has 2 Transactions each, then new payment list will have 10 payment objects.

Edit:
@Nikolas Charalambidis answer works perfectly fine.

To set it back to xml document. Can someone pls let me know if this approach is fine

```
q.forEach(p->{
            //q.forEach(p->{
                BigDecimal s = pmtInf.getSum();
                short t = pmtInf.getNum();
                cs.getGH().setSum(s);
                cs.getGH().setNum((short) t);
                cs.getPmt().add(p);
                document.setCstmrCdtTrfInitn(cs);
                 /str.add(getJAXBObjectToXML(document, Doc.class));
                cs.getPmtInf().clear();
            });
```

Comment: Please show us what you already done. We don't see the list that need to be transformed neither any business-logic code at all.

Comment: @Zefick Thanks for checking. The new payment list will be replacing the existing payment list. Above Classes are representation of an XML object. Here I need to split the xml , such that transformed xml will have pmtlist where each payment has a single transaction instead of multiple transactions

Comment: Is this homework? If it is, why not just post the whole homework assignment instead of breadcrumb feeding the tasks? Why not just do that even if it's not homework?

Comment: @Shark I am able get the expected results but I was just wondering if the approach is fine. Here I am clearing pmt list adding pmt each time. Maybe I should I have opened a new question? I ll make sure to do that for any further clarifications. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple. You need to iterate through each payment (`Ptm`) and then through each transaction (`Transaction`) while retaining the reference to the payment (`Ptm`) for creating the identical one with a single-item list of the transaction (`Transaction`). There are three basic ways I can come up with from scratch and they don't differ in principle:

**Java 7** and earlier (though this solution is ok to be used in the later versions):

```
List<Pmt> list = new ArrayList<>();
    pmtList.forEach(p ->
        p.getTrList().forEach(tr ->
            list.add(new Pmt(p.getId(), p.getB(), singletonList(tr)))));
```

**Java 8** - **Java 15** (though this solution is ok to be used in the later versions):

```java
List<Pmt> list = pmtList.stream()
    .flatMap(p -> p.getTrList()
        .stream()
        .map(tr -> new Pmt(p.getId(), p.getB(), singletonList(tr))))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Java 16** and newer:

```java
List<Pmt> list = pmtList.stream()
    .mapMulti((Pmt p, Consumer<Pmt> c) -> {
        p.getTrList().forEach(tr ->
            c.accept(new Pmt(p.getId(), p.getB(), singletonList(tr))));
    })
    .toList();
```

Comment: This  works perfectly fine
But my only conecern is I had to add a a constructor to my inner static class(Pmt) object which was generated using XJC plugin to convert XML to java

 List<Pmt> q = pmtList.stream()
     .flatMap(p ->  p.getTrList().stream()
       .map(tr -> new Pmt(p.getId(), p.getB(),...., Collections.singletonList(tr))))
     .collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: I suggest you to mark the answer as accepted as an idicator this question has a solution (solely up to you). What you ask now, I believe, is out of scope of this question and is rather related to XML codegen. Feel free to create a new follow-up question.

Comment: @ Nikolas Charalambidis Thanks for the suggestion. I marked the answer as accepted now.
I was unaware  of that option earlier  but I did try to upvote earlier but it showed "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: Great! And as I said, feel free to ask the question. Me or someone else will help you!